# Checking Empty Edittext on the diskIO().execute method

Tags: java, android

I cant seem to check my Edit text for empty insertion into my database. Here is my code. I am using the TextUtils.isEmpty to check but I keep creating empty info when the user just clicks add. I want the button to send the toast message if it is empty. What am I doing wrong.

```
    public void onSaveButtonClicked() {

        String description = mEditText.getText().toString();
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(mEditText.getText())){

            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Record a Task", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        int priority = getPriorityFromViews();
        Date date = new Date();

        final TaskEntry task = new TaskEntry(description, priority, date);
        AppExecutors.getInstance().diskIO().execute(() -> {
            if (mTaskId == DEFAULT_TASK_ID ) {
                // insert new task
                mDb.taskDao().insertTask(task);
            } else {
                //update task
                task.setId(mTaskId);
                mDb.taskDao().updateTask(task);
            }
            finish();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to return inside that if check to see if its empty, so the rest of the function isn't executed when its empty.